# Angular using fetched data outside function scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm returning a JSON object via a $http.get. I'm able to get the result set, and it's an array, but when I try to access the object outside the fetch() I'm getting undefined. Not sure what I'm missing, in order to do this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks Jimi.

```
      myObject.fetch().then(function(myData) {
            $scope.myData = myData;
        });

       console.log($scope.myData)
```

Comment: Is this how your code actually looks?  In this case, the `console.log` will be running before the callback function has actually run and set `$scope.myData`

Comment: Put `console.log(1)` into the callback, and the similar with the number `2` outside. Run and see results. Thoughts?

Comment: so do I need to setTimeout?

Comment: What will it change?

Comment: @Jimi the point is that `myObject.fetch()` will be started and IMMEDIATELY continue with `console.log($scope.myData)`, although the fetch hasn't finished yet.

Whatever you want to execute after fetch() returns, put it into a function and call it from within fetch().then()

Comment: 2 is consoled out first.... DOH

Comment: thanks to all for the comments. Much appreciated.I wanted to run a filter on the results so I'll try this inside the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Your **$scope.myData** is undefined until **fetch()** finishes execution and calls the passed callback function.

in your example, **console.log()** is being called before the completion of myObject.fetch()

In the following example, it will most probably work (don't do it!)

```
setTimeout(function(){
 console.log($scope.myData) 
}, 2000);
```

I'm not telling you to do it this way, actually its a very bad way. best practice is to use that scope variable within the callback function only, since that where its actually set.